# How cam we place the layouts in flutter at center

Tags: android-studio, flutter, layout

I want to place the card in the center
here the code

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var myActivity=["Join Meeting","Create Meeting", "Schedule Meeting","Yet to be decided"];
    var myGridView = new GridView.builder(
      itemCount: myActivity.length,
      gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index) {
        return new GestureDetector(
          child: Card(
            elevation: 5.0,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, left: 10.0),
              child: Text(myActivity[index]),
            ),
          ),
          onTap: () {
            showDialog(
                barrierDismissible: false,
                context: context,
                child: CupertinoAlertDialog(
                  content: Text(myActivity[index],),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                        child: Text("Ok"))
                  ],
                )
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: myGridView,
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two things required to do that first wrap Grid Widget inside `Center` Widget & give `GridView` property as `shrinkWrap: true,`

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("In Test Widget");
    // TODO: implement build
    var myActivity=["Join Meeting","Create Meeting", "Schedule Meeting","Yet to be decided"];
    var myGridView = new GridView.builder(
      itemCount: myActivity.length,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index) {
        return new GestureDetector(
          child: Card(
            elevation: 5.0,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, left: 10.0),
              child: Text(myActivity[index]),
            ),
          ),
          onTap: () {
            showDialog(
                barrierDismissible: false,
                context: context,
                child: CupertinoAlertDialog(
                  content: Text(myActivity[index],),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                        },
                        child: Text("Ok"))
                  ],
                )
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: myGridView),
    );
  }
```

Comment: @vaibhavjain: Could you please accept the answer, so that others can find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

To display the GridView at the center of the screen, you can simply wrap `myGridView` inside a `Center` widget like this..

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: myGridView),
    );
```

You also need to set the GridView's `shrinkWrap` parameter to true. Otherwise gridView will take up the whole screen and so visually the `Center` widget will have no effect on its position.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your view(Card) with Row component and set **mainAxisAlignment** attribute to **MainAxisAlignment.center**  like below.

---

```
 child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Card(
            elevation: 5.0,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, left: 10.0),
              child: Text(myActivity[index]),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your layout in a Column() and set MainAxisAlignment to center.

Column(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
child: <--YOUR EXISTING LAYOUT -->)

It can also center horizontally with crossAxisAlignment.